# Find the exact lambda that caused the cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I created an alarm in Cloudwatch that will email responsible people when there are errors across all lambdas.
The problem is when i receives an alarm, i do not know how to find the exact lambda that cause this (i have over 100 lambdas). Is there a easy way to find out which lambda caused the alarm?

Metric: lambda -> across all functions -> errors

Statistic: Sum

Period: 5 minutes

Comment: How have you defined this alarm? What metric triggers it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, i have edited my question

Comment: Did you check from the CloudTrail events?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the alarm **trigger an AWS Lambda function**.

The Lambda function could then **retrieve all alarms for Lambda errors**, looking for which alarms would have contributed to the metric. The Lambda function could then construct a more informative message to send via email or via an Amazon SNS topic.

Comment: but how can we achieve this? How our lambda identifies the exact function name?

Comment: @Tula I'm thinking that the Lambda function would need to iterate through each AWS Lambda function, and retrieve recent CloudWatch metrics to find which one(s) triggered an error. I also stumbled across this interesting product while doing a web search on the topic: [AWS Lambda Error Tracking](https://sentry.io/for/pythonawslambda/)